# Angular won't connect to WebSocket, but .NET does

Tags: angular, websocket

I'm attempting to connect to a WebSocket for frequent updates from a 3D printer. (The server runs Moonraker which hosts a WebSocket)

I am able to successfully connect to the socket in .NET with zero issues:

```
var url = new Uri("ws://192.168.2.234/websocket");

using (var client = new WebsocketClient(url))
{
    client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reconnection triggered. Type: " + info.Type);
    });

    client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(msg =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message Received: " + msg);
    });

    client.Start();

    exitEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

However attempting the same thing in Angular throws an error.

The angular code:

```
    const newSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.2.234/websocket");

    newSocket.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log("Open: ", event);
    };

    newSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log("message: ", event);
    };

    newSocket.onclose = (event) => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed:', event);
    };

    newSocket.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };
```

I don't see anything in the console that would explain what the root of the error is:

[image]

What is the correct approach for connecting to a WebSocket (NON-secure) from an Angular application? Note that the app is hosted on the default `http://localhost:4200` if that makes any difference...

I've tried using RxJs/Subject in various ways, but I still have issues with connecting. The issue is instant, there's no delay before an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue was related to "localhost".
Launching my Angular app using `ng serve --host=0.0.0.0` AND opening the browser to my machine's IP instead of localhost (IE: `http://[machine-ip]:4200`), the web socket connects successfully.